# Deny IP RANGE access to a directory in IIS 6.0?

Tags: .htaccess, iis, directory, ip, range

the title says it all.

How can I deny access to a directory in IIS 6.0 *public website* ( or how do i name it) through a file ( like  the htaccess for linux/apache ).

If i wasn't clear, let me show you an example of my question, how do i convert this **.htaccess** into IIS (6.0) and save/use it as A FILE, if its possible:

```
deny from 11.22.0.0/19
deny from 44.55.0.0/19
```

Thank you.